# Symfony2 - Method name must begin with findBy or findOneBy

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entities

Firstly let me say, I know that this issue has cropped up before but none of the solutions seemed to have worked. And, also, I am not a new member I just could not remember my login details so I had to re-register....

Basically, I have the job of rehashing an existing Symfony2 project which was never completed and not really well put together. However, for some strange reason I am suddenly getting the above error when trying to call a method "count" within a repository called Customer.

Here is the method within the Repo (bear in mind my directory is not called Acme, it is merely replaced here for simplicity):

```
public function count($type)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(c) FROM AcmePagesBundle:customer c WHERE c.status = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

And it is being called from the main twig template like so:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeCustomerBundle:Customer:count', {'type':'private'})) }}
```

The error I receive when running the application is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Undefined method 'count'. The method name must start with either
>   findBy or findOneBy!") in
>   AcmePagesBundle::main.html.twig at line 30.

I'm using the latest version of Symfony which I believe is 2.7. I'm sure it was working before but after clearing the cache and re-generating the entities it just seems to have messed something up. I've tried most other suggestions but now am at a loss.

If anyone can shed any light on this I would appreciate it very much, thank you.

Michael

**EDIT:**

CustomerRepository.php file:

```
namespace Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function countAll()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(c) FROM AcmePagesBundle:Customer c')
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
    public function count($type)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(c) FROM AcmePagesBundle:Customer c WHERE c.status = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', $type)
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
    public function reverseOrder()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT c FROM AcmePagesBundle:Customer c ORDER BY c.id DESC')
            ->getResult();
    }

    public function lastTen()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT c FROM AcmePagesBundle:Customer c ORDER BY c.id DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getResult();
    }

    public function getCustomerByDefaultAddress($id)
    {
      return $this->getEntityManager()
          ->createQuery('SELECT c FROM AcmePagesBundle:Customer c WHERE c.defaultaddress = :id')
          ->setParameter('id', $id)
          ->getResult();
    }

    public function getCustomerByAddress($id) 
    {
      return $this->getEntityManager()
          ->createQueryBuilder()
          ->select('c')
          ->from('AcmePagesBundle:Customer', 'c')
          ->innerJoin('c.address', 'a')
          ->where('a.id = :id OR c.defaultaddress = :id')
          ->setParameter('id', $id)
          ->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
    }

}
```

Customer.php entity file:

```
namespace Acme\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=96, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mobile", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $mobile;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_added", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateAdded;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Acme\PagesBundle\Address
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="defaultaddress_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"city" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $defaultaddress;

    /**
     * @var Pet
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet", inversedBy="customer", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_pet",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $pet;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address", inversedBy="customer")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_address",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $status = 'private';

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pet = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->dateAdded = new \DateTime();
    }


    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullname()
    {
        return $this->firstname . ' ' .$this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set telephone
     *
     * @param string $telephone
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * Set mobile
     *
     * @param string $mobile
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setMobile($mobile)
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mobile
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMobile()
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateAdded
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateAdded
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
    {
        $this->dateAdded = $dateAdded;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateAdded
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateAdded()
    {
        return $this->dateAdded;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set defaultaddress
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $defaultaddress
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setDefaultaddress(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $defaultaddress = null)
    {
        $this->defaultaddress = $defaultaddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get defaultaddress
     *
     * @return \Acme\PagesBundle\Address
     */
    public function getDefaultaddress()
    {
        return $this->defaultaddress;
    }

    /**
     * Set pet
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Pet $pet
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setPet(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet $pet = null)
    {
        $this->pet = $pet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add pet
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet $pet
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function addPet(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet $pet)
    {
        $this->pet[] = $pet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove pet
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet $pet
     */
    public function removePet(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Pet $pet)
    {
        $this->pet->removeElement($pet);
    }

    /**
     * Get pet
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPet()
    {
        return $this->pet;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setAddress(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add address
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function addAddress(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove address
     *
     * @param \Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address
     */
    public function removeAddress(\Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address->removeElement($address);
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param string $status
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check under Resources/config/doctrine.  If you have yml or xml files then delete them so your annotation mappings work.  It's quite common to accidentally create them and then forget about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your entity definition: it seems that Doctrine is using the default repository instead of your custom one.

You have to set the `repositoryClass` option inside the `@ORM\Entity` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * [...]
 */
class Group
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: I have the following at the top of my entity: ** `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Repository\CustomerRepository")` so this should technically work right?

Comment: Have you checked the namespace? Does the class `Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Repository\CustomerReposit‌​ory` exist and does it have the correct namespace (`Acme\PagesBundle\Entity\Repository`)?

Comment: Yes, definitely exists and in the correct place with the correct namespace.

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding the full code of your repository and of your entity?

Comment: OK, I've added the repo and entity code into my question, thanks

Comment: The class `CustomerRepository` extends the class `EntityRepository` but there is no `use` line for the latter class. Is it in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes, there is : `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;`

Comment: I had similar problem, but with ODM until I restarted php-fpm.

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the correct entity inside the template? Do you have more than one `Customer` entity definition? Have you cleared the cache? I'm really exhausting my options here :D

Comment: Everything is as it should be, I only have one entity for Customer and I've cleared my cache, re-generated my entities and all other things that are supposed to be done. I guess I'll spend some more time looking at it - thanks for your suggestions though!